# I want to display multiple components in Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-cli

I started studying TypeScript and Vue.
And we are investigating how to import and display multiple components.
But now I have an error and I don't know how to fix it.

If you delete either component in the searchForm.ts file
It can start without error.

Although it may be difficult to see because the files are divided, please understand.

```
This dependency was not found:

* @/components/atmos/icons/searchIcon.vue in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/
dist/cjs.js??ref--14-0!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--14-2!./node_modules/eslint-loader??ref--13-0!./src/components/molecules/searchForm.ts?vue&type=script&
lang=js&

To install it, you can run: npm install --save @/components/atmos/icons/searchIcon.vue
Type checking in progress...
No type errors found
```

fieldinput.Vue

```
<template>
    <v-text-field label="Solo" placeholder="Placeholder" solo></v-text-field>
</template>
<script src="./fieldInput.ts"></script>
```

fieldInput.ts

```
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
@Component
export default class FieldInput extends Vue {}
```

searchIcon.vue

```
<template>
    <v-icon>fas fa-search</v-icon>
</template>
<script src='./searchIcon.ts'></script>
```

searchIcon.ts

```
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
@Component
export default class SearchIcon extends Vue {}
```

searchForm.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <searchIcon></searchIcon>
    <fieldInput></fieldInput>
  </div>
</template>
<script src="./searchForm.ts"></script>
```

searchForm.ts

```
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import searchIcon from "@/components/atoms/icons/searchIcon.vue";
import fieldInput from "@/components/atoms/inputs/fieldInput.vue";

@Component({
  components: {
    fieldInput,
    searchIcon
  }
})
export default class SerachForm extends Vue {}
```

Comment: in the error, the path to the icon is `@/components/atmos/icons/searchIcon.vue`. Could it be that 'atmos' should be atoms'?

Comment: It was my description mistake. fixed.
But the result remains the same.